# Using BlazePose in flutter

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite, mediapipe

I want to make an app which uses Blazepose model (instead of COCO model) which returns 33 body landmark locations. It is created by Mediapipe. Link to download this tflite model is https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/modules/pose_detection/pose_detection.tflite. I want to use this model on live camera feed in a flutter app. any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter . However, it might have old TF version. You can consider importing TensorFlow Lite native C library through flutter's c interop, https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop.

Comment: checkout this projcet. https://github.com/lcw99/FlutterWithMediaPipe